# UITableView repeating cells when scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When i scroll down my UITableView, it starts showing me the same cells that i've already seen, and scrolling around a bit continues to put cells in the wrong place.

Here's the code i'm using. If anything additional is needed then let me know:

.h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController {


    int numberOfRows;

    NSArray *allVaults;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int numberOfRows;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *allVaults;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSString *vaultsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Vaults"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    self.allVaults = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:vaultsPath error:nil];

numberOfRows = [self.allVaults count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        NSString *vaultsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Vaults"];

        NSString *dictionaryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                    vaultsPath,
                                    [self.allVaults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryPath];

        cell.backgroundView = [AHCellCreation backgroundView];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [AHCellCreation selectedBackgroundView];
    cell = [AHCellCreation createCellWithDictionary:dictionary Cell:cell];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT 1: Image to show what happens when i move most code outside the (cell == nil) if statement:

Before: [image]

After: [image]

EDIT 2:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 82;
}
```

Comment: What is inside the AHCellCreation class? if it sets the text, etc of the cell then it needs to be outside the the `if (cell == nil)` statement

Comment: But then if i put it there, won't it place the cell contents on top of the previous cell contents, again and again every time i scroll?

Comment: See my answer, the problem lies with AHCellCreation, you'd probably be better off by getting rid of AHCellCreation and putting it directly in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks as if you are only setting the cell content when the you're getting a nil back from **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**. You need to set the cell contents every time, not just when you need to create a new cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    AHCell *cell = (AHCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // create a new cell if there isn't one available to recycle
        // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [AHCell blankCell];

    }

    // set the contents of the cell (whether it's a new one OR a recycled one)
    NSString *vaultsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Vaults"];

    NSString *dictionaryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                vaultsPath,
                                [self.allVaults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryPath];

    cell.backgroundView = [AHCellCreation backgroundView];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [AHCellCreation selectedBackgroundView];
    // cell = [AHCellCreation createCellWithDictionary:dictionary Cell:cell];
    [cell populateAHCellWithDictionary: dictionary];
    return cell;
    }
```

**Update** updated code to address second issue. Rework AHCell so that the class method, e.g. **blankCell** returns a new cell with the subviews set up and the instance method, e.g. **populateAHCellWithDictionary:** sets the content.

Comment: This works to a degree - the cells start overlapping each other. I've posted an image to show this above.

Comment: Are you cells all the same height? And, if not, what are you doing in your tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Yup, all the same. Posted that method above.

Comment: Oh, it looks as if you just keep adding new subviews in AHCellCreation.   Look at your code there. The whole dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: approach tries to minimise object creation. So when you recycle you want to just set the contents of the subviews. It's fine to recreate them too and often fast enough. But if you just add them to an existing cell (which is what's now happening since you fixed the first issue), you'll get the overlap you're seeing.

Comment: The overlapping components imply that you are doing something like -addSubview, wihout removing the older components in createCellWithDictionary. The overlapping is occurring when the cell is not getting recycled. You need to remove the existing sub views every time before adding new views.

Comment: Please post the code for AHCellCreation.  Could it be adding new label view each time instead of just changing the text of existing label

Comment: I do add new subviews there, and then i set them up in various ways. Any way to get around that? I could subclass the UITableViewCell to be ah AHTableViewCell, which would contain the elements I need. Then I could put everything needed in the init method, and all individual cell stuff could go after the (cell == nil) statement. Would this work?

Comment: Yes Subclassing the UITablveViewCell is the way to go here if you need references to subviews that you're adding to the cell's contentView other than the one's that UITableViewCell already provides you access to.

Answer (score 2):

In that case `AHCellCreation` class must add the subviews to the cell and then set the text in one go? You need to layout the cell inside the if statement (add the subviews, UILabels, UIImageView etc, and set their frames etc). And set the content outside the if statement.

Basically whatever doesn't change in each row put inside the if statement, but what changes from row to row put outside the if statement.

This is because the code inside the if statement is only reached when the cell is created, almost always its the cells that are visible on the screen when the Table view loads are created.

When you scroll down the cells that disappear off the top of the screen are reused, and put at the bottom. This means that is you have 100 rows, it won't create 100 cells (it only creates the number of cells that can be visible on the screen at a time and the reuses those) , as this would consume a lot of memory, and the scrolling wouldn't be as smooth.