# Background image of UITableViewCell changes sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has a background UIImageView. Few cells have an image as a background and the others don't. The issue I'm facing is that, sometimes (while scrolling and reusing the cells), wrong images appear on wrong cells. And I'm changing the text color to white in such cases. In some cases the image doesn't load but the text is already converted to white. That leads to plain cells as the background and the text color is white. This doesn't happen all the time. But it does happen. This is what I'm doing in my `cellForAtIndexPath`:

```
// Image
    if ((NSNull*) imageString != [NSNull null])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
        [cell.questionImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
            NSArray *array = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
            BOOL visible = NO ;
            for (NSIndexPath *ipath in array) {
                if (ipath.row == indexPath.row) {
                    visible = YES ;
                    break ;
                }
            }

            if (visible)
            {
                QuestFeedTableViewCell *recreateCell = (QuestFeedTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                recreateCell.question.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                recreateCell.questionImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:0.6];
                _postImage = image;
                recreateCell.questionImageView.alpha = 0.8;
                recreateCell.questionImageView.image = image;

                [recreateCell.questionImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
                if (image)
                {
                    recreateCell.question.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    recreateCell.question.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                    recreateCell.answersCount.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    recreateCell.answersCount.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                }
                [recreateCell setNeedsLayout];

                [recreateCell.questionImageView setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
         {
             cell.questionImageView.image = nil;
             cell.question.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:85.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
             cell.question.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:85.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
             [cell setNeedsDisplay];
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.questionImageView.image = nil;
        cell.question.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:85.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.question.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:85.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.answersCount.textColor = [QuestUtility colorFromHexString:@"#757b86"];
        cell.answersCount.tintColor = [QuestUtility colorFromHexString:@"#757b86"];
    }
```

This issue doesn't happen all the time. What would be the best fix? Create separate XIBs for the two?

Answer (score 0):

You know that the reusing cell mechanism. So it is possible that you fetch the image when the cell is at index of 1 but then the cell is dequeued at index of 6 for example, its background changed.

You should keep the indexPath in the success block and when the success block callback, check if the indexPath is in the tableview's `indexPathsForVisibleRows` array, if it is, you get the cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method and assign image to the imageView and other operation...

I have an example of my project on UICollectionView, I think it will help. In the project I use UICollectionView instead of UITableView but its the same on base. I fetch UIImage on the other thread and then assign it to the cell's imageView.

```
    Image *image = (Image *)multimedium ;
    NSString *thumbnaiPath = image.thumbnailPath ;
    UIImage *imageObj = _thumbnailImageCache[thumbnaiPath] ;
    if (!imageObj) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // I omit some time consuming work to get the data
            UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:data] ;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _thumbnailImageCache[thumbnaiPath] = thumbnail ;
                NSArray *array = [_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] ;
                BOOL visible = NO ;
                for (NSIndexPath *ipath in array) {
                    if (ipath.row == indexPath.row) {
                        visible = YES ;
                        break ;
                    }
                }
                if (visible) {
                    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;
                    UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:imageViewTag] ;
                    view.image = thumbnail ;
                }
            }) ;
        }) ;
    } else {
        imageView.image = imageObj ;
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing something similar. But the same issue does happen sometimes.

Comment: @Anil You should get the cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`, don't use the cell that your block kept.

Comment: Edited the question. But its not loading images now.

Comment: @Anil All the cells are not loading images ? Set a breakpoint the see why. BTW I see your edited code, the cell if not recreateCell, if the cell is visible, it is cached by UITableView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50770/discussion-between-anil-and-kudocc)

Comment: @Anil Sorry, I will go out soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if ((NSNull*) imageString != [NSNull null])
{
      cell.questionImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
     //get a dispatch queue

     dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

     //this will start the image loading in bg

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{    

    NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageString];

    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.questionImageView = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
       });
     });

}
```

}

You can also follow following url "[UITableView repeating cells when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056578/uitableview-repeating-cells-when-scrolled)"

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillAppear alloc init storeIndexArray

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";


TimeSheetCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


if (!cell) {

    cell = [[TimeSheetCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if ([self.storeIndexArray containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [cell.checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_selected.png"]];
}
else
{
    [cell.checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box.png"]];
}


cell.timeSheetModel = [self.timeSheetListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

TimeSheetCell *cell = (TimeSheetCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.storeIndexArray addObject:indexPath];

[cell.checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_selected.png"]];


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {

TimeSheetCell *cell = (TimeSheetCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.storeIndexArray removeObject:indexPath];

[cell.checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box.png"]];


}
```